# handsontable - custom html button at the start of every row with action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have handsontable where I have added a custom button in 2nd column, on click of that I want to send the data of that row to server for processing.

so I have written a onClick function for the button. But how to pass the row index of current row to this function is something I am not able to find out.

```
  var data = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
      ['<button onClick="edit(this)">Actual</button>', 5, 10, 12, 13],
      ['<button>2015</button>', 15, -11, 14, 13],
      ['<button>2016</button>', 20, 15, -12, 'readOnly']
    ],
columns: [{renderer: "html"}, {type: "text"}, {type: "text"}, {type: "text"}],
```

Please refer below fiddle to see the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/8cx5a3by/1/

Comment: So what you want is the row index of the selected row right?

Comment: Yes but inside a function which gets called on clicking on the button. I get the button object to the function, but not getting the current row index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hot.getSelected()`. The response is an array of 4 values. The first is the row index, the second is the column index. You could use those in your `edit` function. Just call on `hot.getSelected()` and it should give you the index assuming the click of the button doesn't stop handsontable from selecting that cell.